# Draw lines inside a polygon

Tags: c, svg, queue, line, polygon

I'm working on a college project and a have to read lot of points, put them in a SVG file and make them form a polygon. After that the goal e to fill the polygon with lines. This lines have a distance (d) between them and must be all contained within the polygon.
We were asked to store the points in a circular queue and so far all I could do was to make the polygon, and have no clue on how to make the filling lines.
All this code does is get the points and draw a line to close the polygon (it may look weird because the professor ordered to use void pointers, circular queues and structs)

this is the example we were given : [image]

```
while (aux2 != size) {
    p1 = getElement(q, aux);   // 0 1 2
    p2 = getElement(q, aux2);  // 1 2 3
    aux = aux2;
    aux2++;
    x1 = getpX(p1);
    x2 = getpX(p2);
    y1 = getpY(p1);
    y2 = getpY(p2);

    fprintf(txt, "Criada linha de borda: x1 = %lf, y1 = %lf, x2 = %lf, y2 = %lf, stroke = %s\n", x1, y1, x2, y2, corb);
    fprintf(svg, "\t<line id=\"%d\" x1=\"%lf\" y1=\"%lf\" x2=\"%lf\" y2=\"%lf\" stroke=\"%s\" />\n", i, x1, y1, x2, y2, corb);
    i++;

    if (y1 < menorY) {
        menorY = y1;
    }
    if (y2 < menorY) {
        menorY = y2;
    }
    if (y1 > maiorY) {
        maiorY = y2;
    }
    if (y2 > maiorY) {
        maiorY = y2;
    }
}
p1 = getElement(q, 0);
x1 = getpX(p1);
y1 = getpY(p1);
```

Thank you

Comment: Sort list of line-segments by `x-coordinate`; for every `y = C` horizontal line, check if line passes through a segment (i.e. `C` in range `[y1..y2]`); use a flag to switch on/off when life goes in/out of polygon. Create horizontal segments based on flag.

Comment: Here is one example [Polyfill - ScanLine - g4g](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scan-line-polygon-filling-using-opengl-c/)

Comment: I wish I could use this, but  we cant use the Gl, so no ScanLine. The whole process must be done manually